# why can't get the query result

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i constructed mongodb server and loaded it.
and i use 'node api.js' command to load the api server
but i can't get the query result.
the err and result returns null.

i checked mongod and env collection has 2 documents.
why this happened?

```
var my = new Schema({
            status: Boolean,
            system_mode: Number
    });
var env = mongoose.model('env', my);
env.find().exec(function(err, result){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
    return;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since env schema is pre created you have to add `{ collection : 'env' }` in mongoose schema, because mongoose will create another collection with the plural `envs`, also mongoose schema should be defined one time on load app, not inside request handler

```
var my = new Schema({
            status: Boolean,
            system_mode: Number
    }, { collection : 'env' });
var env = mongoose.model('Env', my);



env.find({}).exec(function(err, result){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
});
```

Comment: i defined collection name env, not Env. you mean i should define collection name Env?

Comment: i tried it and the result is as follows. result: [], err: null

Comment: Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name, please try to add empty object on find function.

Comment: I added empty object, but the same result.

Comment: Please ensure that you have env table in the connected database, 

in the same port same database , and connection url full url to the database mongodb://localhost:27017/usermanagement

Comment: i double checked dbname and collection name. dbname: patrol collection name: env      i use mongo shell command db.env.find().pretty() and the result have 2 object array.

Comment: please run this command `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P` to check if mongodb server working on default port (`27017`)  or not if not the same port so you have to add port to url connection `mongodb://localhost:XXXX/patrol`, also please define `var env = mongoose.model('Env', envSchema) ` under the `new schema` line not inside the api callback

Comment: Sorry for all of this, please only add `{ collection : 'env' }` to the env schema and define new schema and  `mongoose.model` out of api scope

Comment: Thank you, very much, so much. I added {collection: 'env'} and solved the problem. You''ve got a heart of gold. I want to be your friend.

Comment: @JingzhunLi Much welcome, feel free to contact me any time

Comment: Dear, i want you to help me new problem. The url of the problem is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661644/how-to-query-collection-which-has-multiple-schemas-or-models.  I'm sure you can help me.

Comment: Dear, i have another problem with vuejs. Do you know vuejs? if so, i want you help me. thank you. url is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722869/how-can-i-get-the-formid-of-form-element.