# how to query collection which has multiple schemas or models?

Tags: node.js, mongoose-schema

I inserted several documents that use different schemas(or models) in one collection and I need to query the collection through all documents.
query is {reason: {$or: [1, 2]}} and {_id: objectid('xxx')}.
how can i do?

```
var eqAddPendingSchema = new Schema({
    idString: String,
    name: String,
    category: String,
    life_cycle: Number,
    location: String,
    purchase_date: String,
    description: String,
    image: String,
    video: String,
    reason: Number,
    comment: String,
    created_at: Number,
    updated_at: Number
}, {collection: 'equipments_pending'});
var eqBookPendingSchema = new Schema({
    eq_dbId: String,
    user_dbId: String,
    from: Number,
    to: Number,
    reason: Number,
    created_at: Number,
    updated_at: Number
}, {collection: 'equipments_pending'});
inspectionPendingSchema = new Schema({
    user_dbId: String,
    eq_dbId: String,
    status: Number,
    comment: String,
    reason: Number,
    timestamp: Number,
    created_at: Number,
    updated_at: Number
}, {collection: 'equipment_pending'});
maintainPendingSchema = new Schema({
    user_dbId: String,
    eq_dbId: String,
    status: Number,
    comment: String,
    reason: Number,
    timestamp: Number,
    created_at: Number,
    updated_at: Number
}, {collection: 'equipment_pending'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering why you are making many schema's specially for 
inspectionPendingSchema and maintain booth are the same, please find better design.

**I don't know if it's typo error or not you have defined two schema's linked with equipments_pending and other two linked with equipment_pending**

After defining all schema's you have to define modules

```
var aModule = mongoose.model('eqAddPendingSchema', eqAddPendingSchema);
var bModule = mongoose.model('eqBookPendingSchema', eqBookPendingSchema);


var cModule = mongoose.model('inspectionPendingSchema', inspectionPendingSchema);
var dModule = mongoose.model('maintainPendingSchema', maintainPendingSchema);
```

to find if reason equal 1 or 2 and id  equal x

```
aModule.find({ reason: { $in: [1, 2] } , _id: "5d641cd4d65a0b18b22ddd86" } ,(e,d) =>{
        console.log(d);
       ////// change code
        var newd = d;
        newd.newKey = 'newVariable';
        res.send(newd);
      ////////////change end
    });
```

Comment: The reason why I design so is that equipment_pending collection is a temp collection. i think creating 4 temp collection is worse than one temp collection. And I can get other module documents(such as bModule) using aModule.find()?

Comment: Yes you can get all schema's by any module linked with the same collection.

Comment: I don't know the full solution, but what about make status field in each main table ( eq add, eq book ..), the status can be pending or confirmed or whatever state, maybe you will face other states latter.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think your opinion is right and good solution. I think so, but db design is not mine. Thank you again for your help. The problem is solved by your suggestion.

Comment: i inserted above code. And i received the response data, but newkey is undefined. how can i insert new key into that object variable?

Comment: and i can't get the value of key not defined in schema.